# Extract highest values of numpy structured array

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, numpy

I have a structured array called "data" with several scores for the same entry. For the question sake, I reduced "data" to the following 2 columns.

> ```
> queryid    bitscore
> gene1      500
> gene1      480
> gene1      440
> gene2      900
> gene2      300
> ```

What I want to do is to extract the highest values for queryid that are the same, i.e. any common entry for which the bitscore is at least 10% lower than the highest bitscore.

For example only the first 2 entries "gene1" should be conserved as the third one has a bitscore lower than 10% of 500. For gene 2, only the first one should be conserved (this one is easy).

> ```
> queryid    bitscore
> gene1      500
> gene1      480
> gene2      900
> ```

When I make a loop like this one :

```
for i in range(0, lastrow-1, 1):
if data[i]['queryid'] == data[i+1]['queryid']:
    if data[i+1]['bitscore'] < data[i]['bitscore']-(0.01*data[i]['bitscore']):
       data[i+1]['queryid'] = 'DELETE'

data = data[data[:]['queryid'] != 'DELETE']
```

all "gene1" entries will be conserved as 440 is within the 10% of 480.

I could add the highest value to another column that could be kept as reference, but I wanted to check if any of you guys had a better idea about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be much faster to use logical indexing than `for` loops. How about something like this:

```
def high_bitscores(a,qid,thresh=0.9):
    valid = a[a['queryid'] == qid]
    return valid[valid['bitscore'] >= valid['bitscore'].max()*thresh]
```

**Edit:** If you want to return *all* elements in `data` which pass this criterion, you could loop over the unique `queryid` values in `data` and update a set of boolean indices specifying which elements pass the test:

```
def all_high_bitscores(a,thresh=0.9):

    # set of indices for the elements in a that we're going to keep
    keep = np.zeros(a.size,np.bool)

    for qid in set(a['queryid']):
        idx = a['queryid'] == qid
        keep[idx] = a[idx]['bitscore'] >= a[idx]['bitscore'].max()*thresh

    return a[keep]
```

Comment: Nice,... you don't require the data to be sorted. Maybe you mention numpy.unique to get the unique qid.

Comment: either that or `set`, e.g. `for qid in set(data['queryid']): ...`

Comment: Thanks! I got it partly working... I tried combining `set` with what @ali_m proposed and I got it right except that it returns an array for each qid in `set(data['queryid'])`.  I tried to `numpy.concatenate` the arrays returned by the function, but it somehow doesn't work. Any hints?

Comment: @ali_m Thanks Ali! This works even better than the other solution, as both entries don't have to be sorted (I just realized that the other solution skipped `bitscores` that were not sorted from high to low). Cheers!

Comment: @Sara As a more general recommendation: if you work with these sorts of heterogeneous arrays a lot then, as @Felix suggests, `pandas` will probably simplify things a lot. Because you asked a numpy question I wanted to give you a numpy answer, but I almost never use raw structured numpy arrays myself.

Comment: @ali_m Thanks for the advice, I didn't know Panda at all (but I'm new at python). I'll look into it as I mainly work with heterogeneous arrays (I'm in biology and I was advised to use numpy).

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use pandas, it becomes a one-line problem:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

# Taken from Theodros
data = zip(('gene1',) * 3 + ('gene2',) * 2, [500, 480, 440, 900, 300])
dtype = [('queryid', 'S6'), ('bitscore', 'i4')]
struct_arr = np.array(data, dtype=dtype)

# Create pandas DataFrame from NumPy struct array
df = DataFrame.from_records(struct_arr)

# Filter the rows per group
df.groupby('queryid').apply(lambda x: x[x["bitscore"] >= x["bitscore"].max() * 0.9])
```

Produces:

```
          queryid  bitscore
queryid                    
gene1   0   gene1       500
        1   gene1       480
gene2   3   gene2       900
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to iterate over blocks with the same `queryid`. Then you could filter out those records below the threshold. During this step you leave numpy.structured_array data structure and work on individual tuples. By defining `filter` as a generator you can build a new structured array on the fly from the filterd output.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


def filter(struct_arr, threshold):
    for k, g in groupby(struct_arr, key=itemgetter(0)):
        ref = g.next()
        yield ref
        ref = ref[1]
        for e in g:
            if (float(e[1]) / ref) < threshold:
                break
            yield e
```

**Example:**

```
data = zip(('gene_1',) * 3 + ('gene_2',) * 2, [500, 480, 440, 900, 300])
dtype = [('query_id', 'S6'), ('bitscore', 'i4')]
struct_arr = np.array(data, dtype=dtype)


np.fromiter(filter(struct_arr), dtype=dtype)
```

which gives

```
array([('gene_1', 500), ('gene_1', 480), ('gene_2', 900)], 
      dtype=[('query_id', 'S6'), ('bitscore', '<i4')])
```

Comment: Thanks Theodros, your code works just fine (although if I may, the threshold value is missing in the example)! Moreover, it contains a lot of goodies that seem worth to be digging up into. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that the function call is missing the threshold argument (or the function is missing a default): np.fromiter(filter(struct_arr, 0.9), dtype=dtype)

Comment: @Theodros Zelleke For large arrays, your script is way much faster than ali's. It took a little above 6 min to scan through a 4gig database. As for the other script, it's still running after 12 hours! I debugged it and found out that, unlike yours, every chosen query takes half a second to be printed. Of course, your script should be a little slower than 6 min as it skipped `bitscores` that were not properly sorted, but even it shouldn't reach 12 hours! Is `itertools` the main reason?